# Evaluate $\int_c \frac {1}{z^2 +1 } dz $ for $z=0$ to $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\int_c\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$  where $C$ is from $z=0$ to $z=1$

For singular point, $z^2+1=0$ $=> $$z=i$ or $z =-i$

But then these two points are on the boundary line $z=0$, what should I do?

I think Cauchy integral can't work in here because it's not an open interval?

Thanks for help.

Comment: $z=0$ is a point, not a line. This seems to be a real integral, not a complex one.

Comment: Thanks for comment. How can I define an integral is legal to integrate as a real integral? I am really confuse about it, sometimes it works sometimes don't.

Comment: Your integral is just the real integral $$\int_0^1{1\over z^2+1}\,dz$$ isn't it? The singularities at $\pm i$ have no effect on this.

Comment: oh I understood! thanks a lot
forgot to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are integrating over the line segment from $0$ to $1$. $\gamma (t)=t, 0\leq t \leq 1$ defines this path.

By definition this integral is nothing but $\int_0^{1} \frac 1 {1+t^{2}}dt=\arctan t|_0^{1}=\frac {\pi} 4$.

Answer (score 0):

A parametrization of $ C$ is $c(t)=t$ for $t \in [0,1].$ hence

$\int_C {{1}/({z^2+1})} dz = \int_0^1 {{1}/({t^2+1})} dt = \arctan(1)- \arctan(0)= \frac{\pi}{4}.$